# Got error from message.py - paramiko "object of type 'bool' has no len()" when executing fabric.Connection.run()

Tags: python-3.x, paramiko, pyinvoke, python-fabric-2

I use fabric 2.6.0, paramiko 2.9.2 and invoke 1.4.0

Is this bug or something incompatible I got an error like this.

> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/paramiko/message.py",
> line 274, in add_string
> self.add_int(len(s)) TypeError: object of type 'bool' has no len()

when I set `dry=True` I got like this.

```
>>> conn.run('touch hello.txt', dry=True)
touch hello.txt
<Result cmd='touch hello.txt' exited=0>
```

Here's the complete Error that I got.

```
Python 3.7.5 (default, Dec  9 2021, 17:04:37)
[GCC 8.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from fabric import Connection
>>> conn = Connection('192.168.1.16')
>>> conn.open()
>>> conn.is_connected
True
>>> conn.run('touch hello.txt')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<decorator-gen-3>", line 2, in run
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/fabric/connection.py", line 30, in opens
    return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/fabric/connection.py", line 723, in run
    return self._run(self._remote_runner(), command, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/invoke/context.py", line 102, in _run
    return runner.run(command, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/invoke/runners.py", line 380, in run
    return self._run_body(command, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/invoke/runners.py", line 431, in _run_body
    self.start(command, self.opts["shell"], self.env)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/fabric/runners.py", line 57, in start
    self.channel.update_environment(env)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/paramiko/channel.py", line 72, in _check
    return func(self, *args, **kwds)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/paramiko/channel.py", line 332, in update_environment
    self.set_environment_variable(name, value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/paramiko/channel.py", line 72, in _check
    return func(self, *args, **kwds)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/paramiko/channel.py", line 361, in set_environment_variable
    m.add_string(value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/paramiko/message.py", line 274, in add_string
    self.add_int(len(s))
TypeError: object of type 'bool' has no len()
```

and here my ssh config

```
Host *
    Port 22
    User ubuntu
    IdentityFile /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa
```

when I run `ssh 192.168.1.16` from shell can successfully connect with remote machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After debugging for a while, I realize that this error happen because of miss configuration.

The thing that actually happen is that I put some environment variable on `fabric.yaml` so that will loaded automatically when fabric run and the problem happen when I want to open connection to the remote server.

What happen in the back when I run command with fabric is, fabric will open ssh connection using paramiko and then **`try to send the local environment variable that I set in fabric.yaml to the remote machine (this thing that cause the error)`**

You can't send environment variable form local machine to remote using ssh without put the setting into your sshd_config for the `SendEnv` and `AcceptEnv` for your local and remote machine or the alternatives is enable `PermitUserEnvironment yes` this only for remote machine and don't forget to create `environment` file in your remote home directory (home when you do ssh).

Hope my mistake can help another who also has similiar problem.